# Mirth Transformer Error: prefix for element is not bound

Tags: hl7, mirth

I'm getting the following error when trying to convert HL7v3 to HL7v2

The message passed in is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <PRPA_IN201306UV02 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:ns2="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:nhinccommon" xmlns:ns3="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:patientcorrelationfacade" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" ITSVersion="XML_1.0">
            <id extension="4ae5403:12752e71a17:-7b52" root="1.1.1"/>
...
        </PRPA_IN201306UV02>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR-300: Transformer error
>   ERROR MESSAGE:  Error evaluating transformer
>   com.webreach.mirth.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: 
>   CHANNEL:    v3v2ConversionResponseMessage
>   CONNECTOR:  sourceConnector
>   SCRIPT SOURCE:
>   LINE NUMBER:    5
>   DETAILS:    **TypeError: The prefix "S" for element "S:Envelope" is not bound.**
>       at com.webreach.mirth.server.mule.transformers.JavaScriptTransformer.evaluateScript(JavaScriptTransformer.java:460)
>       at com.webreach.mirth.server.mule.transformers.JavaScriptTransformer.transform(JavaScriptTransformer.java:356)
>       at org.mule.transformers.AbstractEventAwareTransformer.doTransform(AbstractEventAwareTransformer.java:48)
>       at org.mule.transformers.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:197)
>       at org.mule.transformers.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:200)
>       at org.mule.impl.MuleEvent.getTransformedMessage(MuleEvent.java:251)
>       at org.mule.routing.inbound.SelectiveConsumer.isMatch(SelectiveConsumer.java:61)
>       at org.mule.routing.inbound.InboundMessageRouter.route(InboundMessageRouter.java:83)
>       at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver$DefaultInternalMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:493)
>       at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:272)
>       at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:231)
>       at com.webreach.mirth.connectors.vm.VMMessageReceiver.getMessages(VMMessageReceiver.java:207)
>       at org.mule.providers.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.poll(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:108)
>       at org.mule.providers.PollingMessageReceiver.run(PollingMessageReceiver.java:90)
>       at org.mule.impl.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:290)
>       at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:650)
>       at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

When I remove the S: tag in front of the Envelope and Body and redefine the namespace to default, it gives me a new error

> TypeError: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:nil" associated with an element type "targetMessage" is not bound."

This is referring to

```
<targetMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:nil="true"/>
```

As if Mirth can't handle the namespaces being defined on the same line as the first use of that element.

Any suggestions would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to uncheck the "Strip Namespace" property on my incoming transformer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the solution, you'll have to ensure that you Strip Namespace from:

- the Source Transformer's **Inbound AND Outbound** Message Template
- the Destination Transformer's **Inbound** Message Template

The Inbound:

[image: Mirth Inbound Message Template Strip Namespace]